# Как добавить строку в поле и удалить строку?

Tags: eclipse, android, java

Собственно только начал знакомство. Хочу по клику на кнопку добавить значение в текстовое поле и по нажатию на вторую кнопку очистить поле или подставить другое значение. Сейчас получается только вставить значение, вторая кнопка не отрабатывает, и не важно передаю я пустое значение или другую строку.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View;

public class SecondAppActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText edtext;
    private EditText butSecond;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        edtext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
        butSecond = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
    }
    public void BatonClick(View v){
        edtext.setText("Пыщ Пыщ");
    }
    public void BatonClick2(View v){
        butSecond.setText("");
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void BatonClick2(View v){
    edtext.setText("");
}
```

Внимательней.

Comment: не сработало

Comment: Работает. Извините, забыл повесить обработчик функции на кнопку.